# Setting up a VPN for my company so that a remote worker can connect through the office IP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

We will have a windows server 2008 r2 in our company. We have some apps which needs to be used only from our office IP. So, I would like to set up a VPN so that a remote worker can connect the internet with the office IP.

A friend of mine just showed me that his company is doing the same thing. He uses a program which enables him to connect the VPN with it.

I have no idea how I can archive this so a head start would be nice for the following questions;

- we reserved a static IP address for our company from the network provider in Turkey. So, how can I make it static on my server?
- How can I set a VPN host on my windows server 2008 r2?
- what does client need in order to access the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll need to get traffic from the VPN service's port on your external IP to the VPN service running on your 2008 Server, most likely using NAT of some kind I assume you've got a firewall or router or something of the kind connecting you to the Internet; this is where it should happen.
- There are any number of VPN services available for Server '08; which one is best should probably be another discussion, but there's a series of articles on Microsoft's remote access server at http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/configuring-windows-server-2008-remote-access-ssl-vpn-server-part1.html.
- The client will need client software of some kind; Microsoft's own clients are mentioned in the linked-to article above.

Comment: thanks for the post. I have seen the post that you have submitted before. now you recommended it and I will definitely have a close look at it.

Comment: I have windows firewall running on my server and it restrict all access to all ports accept some of them which are used by IIS and SQL Server. what kind of path do I need to follow here?

Comment: You'll need to open up access to the port that the VPN service uses.  Which port that is depends on which VPN service you end up using; if it's the MS one, then the firewall settings are on the second page of the article.